# iphone draw over UIScrollView with MultiTouch

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I'm creating methods to use multi-touch taps to draw shapes on top of an image inside a UIScrollView.  I'm thinking that I should just create a new UIView subclass for the shapes and add them as a subView to the main controller that contains the scrollView.

If so, can I simply use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, ... with the new UIView subclass? And if not how do I connect the touches to the drawing logic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the touch method in UIScrollView you need to make your own class for Scrollview which is sub class of the UIscollview and use that class in place of the UIScrollView. As you class is Sub class of UIScrollView you can get all the method of the UIScrollView through object of you class.

Now for getting touch method you will get in you class and using custom delegate you can call in any class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It works except that the circles that I'm trying to draw (using drawRect in the subclass of UIScrollView) are show under the image I added to the scrollView. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not getting your exact problem . can you please elaborate it .

Comment: Thanks.  In my viewcontroller I use the statement:

Comment: In my view controller, I use the statement [scrollView addSubview:myImage]; to add an image to my custom scrollview.  Then in the custom scrollview, I use - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event to detect the touch and locations.  Next, I use - (void)drawRect:(CGRect) rect to create  circles. Finally I use [self setNeedsDisplay] in the - (void)touchesBegan method to draw the circles in the scrollview.  The circles are drawn OK, but under the image that I originally added.  How can I draw the circles over the image?